# How to implement this search query in ionic using ajax post?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter, ionic-framework

[image: screencap]I have this search query in my codeigniter the problem is I dont know how to implement it in ionic. What I want is if I search on the searchbox in my ionic(home.html) ex. "Pepper, Oil" , the result should be the recipe that corresponds with the ingredients like adobo and kaldereta.

user_model.php ( codeigniter - model )

```
public function get_halal($search_values)
{
    $this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('recipe');
    $this->db->join('menu', 'menu.recipe_id = recipe.recipe_id');
    $this->db->join('ingredient', 'ingredient.ingredient_id = menu.ingredient_id');
    $this->db->where('menu.category_id = 1');

    if (strpos($search_values, ',') !== false) {
        $search = explode(',' , $search_values);
        $this->db->like('ingredient.name', trim($search[0]), 'both');
        unset($search[0]);
        foreach ($search as $term) {
            $this->db->or_like('ingredient.name', trim($term), 'both');
        }
    } else {
    //this means you only have one value 
    $this->db->like('ingredient.name',$search_values, 'both');
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

home.php ( codeigniter - controller )

```
public function ajaxSearchHalal()
{
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($postdata)) {
        $data = $this->user_model->get_halal($postdata);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

searchService.js ( ionic )

```
return {
    all: function() {
      return $http.get('http://localhost/admin-recipick/home/ajaxSearchHalal').then(function(result){
        return result.data;
        console.log(result.data);
      });
    }

}
```

controller.js (ionic)

```
RecipeList.all().then(function(payload) {
 $scope.recipedata = payload;

    console.log(payload);
});

 $scope.searcRecipe = function() {
    RecipeList.all();
    $state.go('app.searchRecipe');
};
```

home.html ( ionic - view )

```
   <div class="list list-inset">
      <label class="item item-input">
          <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
          <input type="text" ng-model="" placeholder="(EX. beef, fish, corn)"> 
      </label>
      <button type="button" class="button button-block button-assertive icon ion-search " ng-Click="searcRecipe()"> Search</button>
   </div>
```

Comment: when you call ajaxSearchHalal() what you get? any error?

Comment: I get all the recipe under category_id = 1 . Its seems that the condition was not working sir @PareshGami. I edited and put a screencap above

Answer (score 0):

```
RecipeList.all().then(function(payload) 
{
    console.log(payload.data);
});
```

use payload.data for getting response.